# Densely defined derivations in von Neumann algebra(in norm topology)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

This post is actually a refined question of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4270478/unbounded-derivation-of-von-neumann-algebra).

Let $N$ be an abelian von-Neumann algebra. Define densely defined derivation to be derivation $\delta:D(\delta)\rightarrow N$ where the domain is dense subalgebra in norm topology. Does $N$ admit any closed densely defined derivations? I am most interested in $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ and $L^{\infty}[0,1]$. My gut feeling is that it doesn't since their real rank is zero, but I don't know how to show that.